# Firebird 2.5 sql error code = -104. Invalid token

Tags: c#, firebird

I do request and get an error

> Invalid token. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Token unknown
>   - line 1, column 66. DATE.

```
DATE char(25)
```

All fields work, without a date

```
INSERT INTO BASE(ID,INV_NUM,PRODUCER_TYPE,PRODUCER_COUNTRY,MODEL,DATE,DEVICE_TYPE,NAME,SURNAME,MIDDLE,DOB) VALUES(1,112,'D-Link','China','AP','12.10.2004','Asd','Wood','Ivanov','Middle','07.01.2014')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `DATE` is a reserved word (in standard SQL and in Firebird). You will need to quote it to be able to use it as a column (or other object) in a query.

So change it to:

```
INSERT INTO BASE(..., MODEL, "DATE", DEVICE_TYPE,...)  ...
```

For dates you shouldn't use a `CHAR` type, but a `DATE` type instead.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `Date()` for dates... 07.01.2014 use this 2014-01-07

```
INSERT INTO BASE(ID,INV_NUM,PRODUCER_TYPE,PRODUCER_COUNTRY,MODEL,DATE,DEVICE_TYPE,NAME,SURNAME,MIDDLE,DOB) VALUES(1,112,'D-Link','China','AP','2004-10-12','Asd','Wood','Ivanov','Middle','2014-01-07')
```